# get selected element offset value using jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have created dynamic textbox controls in asp using jquery as following

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddField" runat="server" Text="Add Field" OnClientClick="createInput(); return false;" />
```

Jquery function

```
function createInput() {
        var $input = $('<div class="dragMe" style="position: absolute; padding-top:6px; top:30px; left:100px; zIndex: 5"> <input type="text" class="customText" value="drag me.." style="outline: 0;"/><div style="visibility:hidden"><a class="remove_block" href="#">Remove</a></div></div>');

        $input.appendTo($("[id$=pnlCertificate]"));
        $(".dragMe").draggable();
        $(".dragMe").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "#c0c0c0");
            $('.dragMe a').css("visibility", "visible");
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).css("background", "none");
            $('.dragMe a').css("visibility", "hidden");
        });
        $('.remove_block').on('click', function (events) {
            events.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('div').eq(1).remove();
        });
        $('.dragMe').on('click', function (events) {
            getOffset();
        });
    }

    function getOffset() {
        var offset = $('.dragMe :input').offset();
        events.stopPropagation();
        $("[id$=txtBox1]").val(offset.top);
        $("[id$=txtBox2]").val(offset.left);
    }
```

I want the offset values of dynamic textbox to be displayed on following textboxes

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what ClientIDMode you have set, this should do the job (just the getOffset function needs changing). It will insert the client ID of your textbox controls into the JavaScript.

```
function getOffset() {
    var offset = $('.dragMe :input').offset();
    events.stopPropagation();
    $("$<%= txtBox1.ClientID %>").val(offset.top);
    $("$<%= txtBox2.ClientID %>").val(offset.left);
}
```